# Is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]}{(2, X)}$ a Euclidean Domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

Is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]}{(2, X)}$ a Euclidean Domain?

Definition for a Euclidean Domain (ED) I tend to use is the following: Let $R$ be an integral domain and $R$ supports at least one Euclidean function, that is there at least exits one $\phi$ such that $\phi: R^{*}\to \mathbb{N}_0$ so that for any $a,b\in R^{*}$, either $a|b$ or $\exists r,s\in R$ such that $b=ar+s$ and $\phi(s)<\phi(a).$ (This definition is not very important to my question but I put it out here so that we don't have any potential confusions.)

Now I recognise all elements in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]}{(2, X)}$ are in the form $f(y)+(2,X)$ such that $f(y)\in \mathbb{Z}[Y]$ and the constant term of $f(y)$ has to be odd.

I had a couple ideas of proving or disproving if an integral domain is an ED. One would be if I could prove it is not a PID. Also I thought about the possibility of having an isomorphism to other, more familiar, rings. However, I did not manage to get far with either, could someone please help me to go a little further?

Comment: Hint: Your ring is isomorphic to the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[Y]$.

Comment: "The constant term of  $f(y)$ has to be odd" does not allow for the class of $0$: $0+(2,X)$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Just curious, how did you see that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2[Y]$ straightaway? Is it just by First Isomorphism Theorem and find a homomorphism that has the kernel $(2,X)$?

Comment: Modding by $2$ makes all the coefficients in $\Bbb F_2$ and modding by $X$ gets rid of all $X$s; what's left is $\Bbb F_2[Y]$. Yes you can prove that with 1st Iso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider the map $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y] \to \mathbb{F}_2[Y]$ given by $f(X,Y) \mapsto f(0,Y) \bmod 2$. Prove that this map is a surjective ring homomorphism and that its kernel is $(2,X)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $k$ is a field then $k[x]$ is an Euclidean domain, with norm $\phi(f)=\deg(f)$ for $f\in k[x]$.